# Howto Exit swift-language terminal mode

Tags: macos, swift

I'm having problems about how to exit the swift-language's terminal mode.
I type swift in terminal on my Mac Air (Yosemite),
And I got to swift's terminal mode,, something similar to python's.

But in python i can use quit() to exit that mode.
However, in swift,, I didn't find such a method..

So I exit the whole terminal by 'command + q'..

Then, I got gabbage like these:

```
      20282   0.0  0.0        0      0   ??  Z     8:14PM   0:00.00 (repl_swift)
      20372   0.0  0.0  2441988    652 s000  S+    8:30PM   0:00.00 grep swift
      20168   0.0  0.0        0      0   ??  Z     8:00PM   0:00.00 (repl_swift)
```

What's worse,,, even kill -9  can't kill the repl_swift process.

I guess the only thing I can do is reboot now..
But really curious why~~ Is the swift-terminal mode still in beta version? :)

Comment: Why can't we `control-c` like everything else?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Type `control-d` to exit REPL.

`control-d` is the end of file character and it's used by various command line tools to mark the end of user input.

---

*Added by a later editor*

You can also quit the Swift REPL by typing `:quit`, `:q`, or `:exit`

Answer (score 11):

You can also type `:exit`, `:quit`, or `:q` at the Swift REPL prompt instead of `control-d`. Type `:help` at the Swift REPL for all available commands.

[image]